# Driving a motor with a high-side PMOS switch. Does it need a flyback diode?

Tags: switches, flyback, pmos

I'm looking to use a high-side PMOS switch to control a brushed DC motor. Is it necessary to add a flyback diode for this implementation? And if so, how/where exactly should it be added?

[image: My LTspice circuit]

Comment: The diode goes across the motor. It should be oriented in such a way that it is reverse biased during normal operation.

Answer (score 6):

> *Is it necessary to add a flyback diode for this implementation? And if
> so, how/where exactly should it be added?*

Yes, usually necessary and, it goes here: -

[image]

You've also drawn M2 upside down.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean about the PMOS being upside down?

Comment: Source and drain are incorrectly reversed @solderballz666

Comment: In a MOSFET, the source is an internal source of carriers to the channel, and the drain is a sink of the same carriers.  So in an NMOS, the source delivers electrons -- and must be _given_ electrons, by connecting it to a circuit point at a lower potential than the drain.  In a PMOS, the source delivers _holes_.  While you can't give it holes directly, you can connect it to a point at _higher_ potential to the drain, to remove electrons -- which effectively gives it holes.  So you have M2 set up such that the current through it is going the wrong way.

Comment: @solderballz666 if we are done here you should take the 2 minute tour to find out what you should do next. If you need help let me know: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

If you connect the MOSFET properly and you use an appropriately rated avalanche rated MOSFET you do not need the external flyback diode. These have been available starting in about 2000 with the trench process then hexfet followed suite. Most modern data sheets give this information as part of there standard datasheet. When I was doing UIS testing it was defined as the amount of energy the MOSFET can withstand when it is set into avalanche mode or its breakdown voltage is exceeded. The test circuit is also on most data sheets. That value is determined by the Avalanche Current, which is done during an Unclamped Inductive Switching test. This is a lot dependent value so the data sheets are conservatively rated but do not count on them to exceed that as there are some odd lots.